# Adding row numbers by field in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a point layer of features of interest that covers around 200 river catchments (each river catchment has between 50 and 100 associated points). I have joined attributes from the river catchments polygon shapefile to my points layer, so that each point is labelled with the river catchment name in which it falls. I would now like to add sequential row numbers by field to my point file, so that numbering starts at '1' for each river catchment.

I can select by each river catchment and use the @row_number to add sequential numbering, but it's laborious.

Is there a quicker, more automated way of doing it?

Answer (score 5):

Use this expression to create increasing numbers separately for points belonging to each river (see below for a variant if points are in an arbitrary order along each river):

```
array_find(
    array_agg( $id, rivername),  -- replace rivername by the name of the river layer
    $id
)+1
```

**Explanation**: `array_agg()` aggregates the id of all features of the point layer that belong to the same river in an array. The function `array_find()` then get's the index (position) of this id inside the array. As the first element starts with 0, add 1.

*The expression used as dynamic label for the points:*
[image]

### Variant

If points are randomly distributed and not created in the correct order along the river, you can't use the `$id` to get an increasing order along the river. In this case, use this solution that works indifferent of the creation order of the points, using the funtion [`line_locate_point`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#line-locate-point):

```
with_variable(
    'dist',
    'line_locate_point( overlay_nearest (''rivername'',$geometry)  [0],$geometry)', -- change rivername to the name of the line layer
    array_find(
        array_sort (
        array_agg( 
            eval(@dist), 
            line  -- attribute name in the point layer of the river the feature belongs to
        )
    ), 
    eval(@dist)
    )+1
)
```

*Black label: `$id`/creation order of the points; red label created dynamically by the expression above:*
[image]

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped. The policy of this site is to avoid thank you messages. It encourages you instead to accept the answer if it solved your Problem, See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers